# C++: Evaluate own mathematical function (function-array like multidimensional analysis) entry-wise

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Hey there,
I want to evaluate a mathematical function (user-defined) which returns several values in an array (this function is a vector based function f:R^n->R^m with n input coordinates and m output functions) in C++ for certain parameters, e.g.:

```
double *my_func(const mxArray *point)
{
    double *dat = mxGetPr(point);
    double *vals = new double[ 3 ];

    vals[0] = dat[0]*dat[0]*dat[0]*dat[0]*dat[0];
    vals[1] = sin(dat[0])*dat[1]*dat[2]*dat[2]*cos(dat[1]);
    vals[2] = exp(dat[0])*sin(dat[0])*dat[3];

    double *pnt = vals; 
    return pnt;
}
```

Currently I do this on the CPU. So I call the function once and get back an array with all function values. As I want to parallelize it now on the GPU, I thought about how to do it.

I assume it would be kind of stupid to evaluate my_func() completely in each thread since than each thread would calculate the whole function-array. **Is this the right assumption?**

Would there be any way to comfortable calculate only the n-th element of the function-array and return it, so that 5 threads could easily calculate the function-array in parallel instead of one CPU calculating it completely 'alone'?

The only way I could think off was:

```
double my_func0(const mxArray *point)
{
    double *dat = mxGetPr(point);
    return dat[0]*dat[0]*dat[0]*dat[0]*dat[0];
}
double my_func1(const mxArray *point)
{
    double *dat = mxGetPr(point);
    return sin(dat[0])*dat[1]*dat[2]*dat[2]*cos(dat[1]);
}
double my_func2(const mxArray *point)
{
    double *dat = mxGetPr(point);
    return exp(dat[0])*sin(dat[0])*dat[3];
}
```

etc... But this would be quite 'uncomfortable' for the user who uses the program later because he always would have to create new C++ functions if he wants to extend the function-array instead of just adapting ONE single C++-function. And a further problem would be: I have to dynamically call the function since the number of functions is 'dynamic' and thus I would have to do a call to `my_func_%%i%%` and don't know if this is a good way to do it... So the question is if there would be a better way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "user_defined" I presume you mean that someone else writes `my_func()` and then your code calls it?

If this is the case, consider running many calls to `my_func()` in parallel rather than trying to break the function up. This means whoever writes `my_func()` only needs to write one function, and you will be responsible for delegating multiple calls, ensuring they have the correct data to work on, and gathering up the results.

**Update Based on Comments**

In your situation, If the operation required to calculate each member of the `vals` is different then the user would either have to parameterise the `my_func()` by the index required; as you suggested `double my_func(const mxArray *point, const unsigned & index)`, note how it now returns a single double value as opposed to the whole result array. Or provide a different `my_func()` for each index; `double my_func_n(const mxArray *point)`.

You could then call this function or set of functions from as many different threads as you like and get a single result for further computation. We are ignoring many concurrency issues however to do with reading/writing data simultaneously which need thinking about.

**General Mutlitasking Advice**

Before looking into multitasking with your GPU have a look at standard multithreading on a CPU (I recommend Boost Thread Libraries to help: http://www.boost.org/). Once you see how threads are created and used you may find you better understand what you can do with them and how you'd go about doing it.

Multitasking with a GPU becomes more useful if you are applying mathematical functions to very large matrices or vectors and it is possible to use hardware implementations of certain graphical functions to achieve the mathematical result. There are further libraries to support GPGPU (General Purpose GPU) programming, such as OpenCL, Nvidia's CUDA, or ATI's Stream. Have a look at what these libraries provide to give you an idea of how applicable they are to your situation.

Comment: And how would you than do it if I should write it to ONE function? The only thing I could think of (but that would look pretty ugly) is: `double myfunc(double* point, int index) { if(index == 0) return (*point) * (*point) elseif(index == 1) return ... elseif(index == 2) return ...}`

Comment: Can you expand a little bit, by showing me how you actually use `my_func()` in your main code?

Comment: Okay currently I do it like that: `funcValues = my_func(point)` where funcValues is a pointer to a dynamic created array in my_func(point) containing the values of the single mathematical functions (as can be seen in the first post whereas point is a pointer to an array containing the mathematical coordinates to evaluate). than I do something like `funcValues2 = my_func(point+h)` and than I calculate numerical derivative via `(funcValues2-funcValues2)/h` (pseudo-code ...). As `funcValues` is an array I want to parallelize it so I can calculate all those derivatives in parallel

Comment: And as each thread should than calculate one derivative there's no use in calculating `funcValues = my_func(point)` in each thread since each thread calculates only ONE derivative and thus only needs ONE element out of the returned pointer-array. That's why I thought about splitting the function in several functions so that thread1 does: `double derivative1 = (my_func1(coords+h)-my_func1(coords))/h`, ... threadN does: `double derivativeN = (my_funcN(coords+h)-my_funcN(coords))/h`

Comment: Okay thanks so far again. So both of your suggestions is about the stuff which I suggested also and I really really wonder if there isn't any solution which just is more 'beautiful' (don't know the right term to express that the code is the opposit of ugly^^) and good to maintain. Two things I still think about: **first**: When I have everything in ONE func and use the switch() statement (or if-elseif-elseif...) with 100 or 200 cases (for 100 or 200 single functions), isn't that overhead about the conditional statements?

Comment: **second** thing I wonder about: When I use the method to define each function itself in C++: `double my_func_n(const mxArray *point)` is there any way to dynamically call such a function? Let's say I have 100 functions `my_func_1()` to `my_func_100()` and want to call them in sequentiell mode (sequentiel just as example here to focus on my real question): how to do it like that: `for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { XYZ }`, XYZ needs to be filled...!? in PHP you could do `$func = 'my_func_' . $i; $func()` but how to call functions dynamically in C?

Comment: Are there no relationships between the calculations and each `index`? If not someone has to write how to calculate each one. If the operations you do have a mathematical relation to the `index` then it's possible to write a function that doesnt need to `switch` for every `index`.

Comment: reply to second comment: look into function pointers and templates. Using the power of these 2 features you could achieve this. You can build a collection of function pointers to all the functions using template classes and templated functions and then call each function.

Comment: It's likely that there is a more elegant solution if we consider the problem from a slightly higher level, but given what you've said about what you want to do here... someone has to write code to handle every index

Comment: okay thanks so far. About your first comment: No there's no relation to the `index`. Just some user-written mathematical functions which calculate a value just by using the input-coordinates. Nothing more than that.